# How to manage a 1GB SQL export file?

Tags: sql, oracle, import

I have a 1 GB text file full of `INSERT ROWs` SQL commands. My destination database is an oracle DB in a remote server.

To import the whole 1 GB file at once would take a lot of time (Upload time + time to process the queries).

What are the recommendations and good practices to deal and manage big SQL export files?

Comment: Did you try just running it? You might not actually have a problem yet.

Comment: Traditionally, large data volumes are imported as flat files into Oracle, using a command line tool called SQL*Loader or a database technique called external tables. You might want to consider disabling indexes before the load and rebuild them afterwards.

Comment: Don't understand why this question is closed. It seems perfectly clear, and I've had exactly this problem to deal with before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the file through `gzip` to compress it (if not done), transfer it manually via scp or so. Then run the actual import locally on the server over ssh.

The main problem shouldn't be the import, that runs quite fast usually. Uploading and importing at the same time can be problem due to connection issues, so it is better to upload the file first and import it.

Comment: +1 In addition, you may want to try to combine your INSERT statements.  For example, `insert into your_tables select 1 from dual union all select 2 from dual ...`.  One large statement will generally run significantly faster than several small statements.  Although you also don't want to combine them too much, probably just dozens or a hundred, or you may run into some parsing performance issues.  Combined with running on the server, I wouldn't be surprised if you this process runs 10 to a 100 times faster than before.